# Javascript merge/reduce same multi dimensional objects

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash, javascript-objects, reduce

based on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661953/2392461, i open a new question with sample data.

I want to merge/reduce this:

```
var array = [{
  'key1': {
    'key11': 0,
    'key12': 1
  },
  'key2': 0,
  'key3': {
    'key31': [1, 2],
    'key32': {
        'key321': 3,
        'key322': [1, 2]
    }
  },
  'key4': 'test'
  }, {
  'key1': {
    'key11': 1,
    'key12': 9
  },
  'key2': 2,
  'key3': {
    'key31': [4, 3],
    'key32': {
        'key321': 6,
        'key322': [8, 9]
    }
  },
  'key4': 'test'
  }, {
  'key1': {
    'key11': 3,
    'key12': 4
  },
  'key2': 7,
  'key3': {
    'key31': [3, 2],
    'key32': {
        'key321': 6,
        'key322': [7, 8]
    }
  },
  'key4': 'test'
}];
```

to this:

```
{
  'key1': {
    'key11': [0, 1, 3],
    'key12': [1, 9, 4]
  },
  'key2': [0, 2, 7],
  'key3': {
    'key31': [[1, 2], [4, 3], [3, 2]],
    'key32': {
        'key321': [3, 6, 6],
        'key322': [[1, 2], [8, 9], [7, 8]]
    }
  },
  'key4': 'test'
}
```

the reduce function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40668315/2392461) from @stasovlas with lodash looks good but i need to go deeper in the object.

```
_.reduce(data, function(result, item) {
    var added = _.find(result, {
        key4: item.key4
    });
    if (_.isObject(added)) {
        //!! better to merge with new object and add result to array again to avoid mutable
        added = _.mergeWith(added, item, function(addedVal, itemVal, key) {
            if (key === 'key4') {
                return addedVal;
            }
            return _.concat(addedVal, itemVal);
        });
        return result;
    }
    return _.concat(result, item);
}, []);
```

result is here a merged object only in layer 1 of the object.

```
[ { key1: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    key2: [ 0, 2, 7 ],
    key3: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    key4: 1 } ]
```

i have no idea how to get my result. i think i have to iterate each object n times. n is the depth of the object.

is this the right way or is it easier than i think?

greetings mok

Comment: what is special with `key4`? why isn't it an array with three `'test'` inside?

Comment: oh sorry i copied a result from another array. but i need one ID key like the „key4“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge each level by iterating the entries of the source object and create either a new object or an array for adding the result. Proceed with child objects.

`key4` gets a special treatment.

```js
function merge(target, source) {
    var singleKey = 'key4';
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
            merge(target[key] = target[key] || {}, value);
            return;
        }
        if (key === singleKey) {
            target[key] = value;
            return;
        }
        target[key] = target[key] || [];
        target[key].push(value);
    });
    return target;
}

var array = [{ key1: { key11: 0, key12: 1 }, key2: 0, key3: { key31: [1, 2], key32: { key321: 3, key322: [1, 2] } }, key4: "test" }, { key1: { key11: 1, key12: 9 }, key2: 2, key3: { key31: [4, 3], key32: { key321: 6, key322: [8, 9] } }, key4: "test" }, { key1: { key11: 3, key12: 4 }, key2: 7, key3: { key31: [3, 2], key32: { key321: 6, key322: [7, 8] } }, key4: "test" }],
    result = array.reduce(merge, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you, i can’t check it right now but tomorrow. key has to be my ID and strings and same values has to be also an array. i will add a key5 with unix timestamps. after finishing reducing the array i will use it to generate timeseries charts

Comment: omg, this is exactly what i want. now i try to understand your code. what exactly happens here: target[key] = target[key] || [];? is it: if target[key] is empty then []?

Comment: this checks if `target[key]` is falsy, like `undefined` and assigns an empty array. an array (despite of the length or values) is a truthy value, so no more assignments happens with a default value.

Comment: ah I did not know that I can use the short version directly with variable assignment.

Comment: thank u, this is art!!! if i see it... i think... okay this make sense but I could never rhyme that in my head.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few improvements, it is more flexible for any kind of this problem.

```
function merge(target, source) {
    var fixedKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'keyn'];

    Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && value.toString() === '[object Object]') {
            merge(target[key] = target[key] || {}, value);
            return;
        }
        if (value && Array.isArray(value)) {
            merge(target[key] = target[key] || [], value);
            return;
        }
        if (fixedKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            target[key] = value;
            return;
        }
        target[key] = target[key] || [];
        target[key].push(value);
    });
    return target;
}
```

Now u can merge/reduce also deeper values/arrays/object, there is no converting from JS Arrays to Objects or otherwise and it is JSON.stringify compatible. You can set an Array of keys which should occur only once.

hope this is helping not only me :)

Comment: great, that you took my answer for your accepted answer, without mentioning ... and then accepting it. if feel exploited.

Comment: sorry, that was not my intention. should i have rather post that as a comment?

Comment: as post it's fine.